# Data on the percentage of Frenchmen who are in favor of allowing UberPOP in France

Tags: data-request, france, survey

I am looking for surveys or any other kind of data source indicating the percentage of Frenchmen who are in favor of allowing UberPOP in France.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to get the share of those having Uber app at their smartphone among all French users of GooglePlay of AppStore.

Comment: @Ilya Unsure, can we see the user location on play/appstore? Also, UberPOP is just one (now illegal) service of Uber.

Comment: That was just an idea to check. Another: probably, some statistics, in aggregated form, could be requested from Uber.

Comment: @Ilya I am sure Uber will give you whatever carefully chosen statistic best supports their case...

Answer (score 2):

You can do sentiment analysis on social media feeds, **but** I suspect there is an inherent overlap (bias) between social media users (e.g. Twitter) and people who are pro-Uber.

To do so with Twitter, you can use the API to search terms related to Uber with the following constraints:
+ located in France (bounding box)
+ tweet text in the French language

In addition to Search, you can measure an endorsement of a view by retweets.

It's not scientific, but if you wanted to make it scientific, you'd have to hit the streets and phone lines and start very randomly sampling people.